# Mean of iid uniform RVs on the cube roots of 1

Tags: probability-theory

If $Y_{n} = \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$,

where $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots X_{n}$ are iid uniformly distributed on the three cube roots of 1,

We want to show that $\frac{Y_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to a multivariate Gaussian and find its covariance matrix.

Why would this be multivariate? Isn't an instantiation of each $X_{i}$ simply a real or complex number (i.e. one of 1, $-1/2+\frac{\sqrt-3}{2}$, $-1/2-\frac{\sqrt-3}{2}$)?

Answer (score 1):

It is multivariate if you consider the real and imaginary parts separately.  You are expected to show that each one converges to a normal distribution and find the mean, variance, and correlation coefficient.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly are the random vectors that are being considered?

Comment: You add up $n$ of the values, divide by $\sqrt n$, and take the real and imaginary parts.  The real part of the sum is the sum of $n$ tosses of a variable with value $+1$ with probability $\frac 13$ and value $-\frac 12$ with probability $\frac 23$.  The imaginary part is the sum of $n$ tosses with values $0,\frac 1{\sqrt 3}, -\frac 1{\sqrt 3}$ each with probability $\frac 13$  The sums are correlated.

Comment: So, then I find that both the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{Y_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converge to $N(0, \frac{1}{4})$ random variables by the central limit theorem. I don't exactly see how this helps me find the covariance matrix of $\frac{Y_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$. Isn't its variance simply $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: The covariance represents the fact that if the real sum is positive you have more $0$ imaginary values in your sum, so the variance of the imaginary sum is reduced.  I don't have the formula at hand, but I believe it involves adding up the products of the real and imaginary parts of your variables.